# Windows Defender Firewal Incoming Rules issue with definition of Protocol + Port only

Tags: windows, firewall, windows-firewall, windows-defender

i faced today an issue, which makes to me no sense and i would like to ask if you know this issue or if something is going wrong on my setup.

I have a Windows Server 2019 and installed an IIS Role on it. (running on https)

I enabled the windows firewall on all 3 profiles (public,domain,private) and i created two rules.

**Outgoing rule** which allow everything (all protocols, all ports) (allow all)

**Incoming Rule**, that TCP Port 443 is allowed for all remotesystems 10.0.0.0/8
I can access the webserver with from the iis server itself, no issues

When i try to reach the url from outside the server, than the connection gets blocked. I can see the block on the activated windows firewall logfile.

After a while I found out that it is only working, if i am creating a predefined rule called

"World Wide Web Services (HTTPS Traffic-In)"

world wide web services https traffic-in
Now I was wondering, why is it not enought to define in the firewall for the protocoll and the TCP Port 443, why do i need to create this "application based rule?"

Do you know what needs to be changed on the Windows Firewall Settings, that I do not need this rule (application rule)?

The Background of the Question is, that I have created a Powershell Script to prepare my Windows IIS Servers with a set of firewall rules i need.

The Script looks like:

```
# enable firewall
Set-NetFirewallProfile -Profile Domain,Public,Private -Enabled True
Set-NetFirewallProfile -DefaultInboundAction Block -DefaultOutboundAction Allow -NotifyOnListen True -AllowUnicastResponseToMulticast True -LogFileName %SystemRoot%\System32\LogFiles\Firewall\pfirewall.log -LogBlocked True
# remove all old settings
Remove-NetFirewallRule *
# Web
New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName 'WEB-INBOUND' -Profile Domain,Public,Private -Direction Inbound -Action Allow -LocalPort 433 -Protocol TCP -RemoteAddress 10.0.0.0/8
```

I could not find an option to create this "predefined rule" with a powershell command.

I found a message on my windows defender firewall: defender firewall
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wzm2.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jloR4.png)